# SQL Divide or group fixed lengthed entries together

Tags: sql, loops, subset, modulus, sublist

i have the following SQL Problem, given a table with a specific column e.g tableX:

```
col1
123
321
456
321
982
666
100
...
```

the amount of rows in this table can vary (even be 0).
What i need is to divide the rows into a coma separate text.

For example, I could put all values into one string
using this

```
SET @LIST= (SELECT ',''' + col1+'''' FROM Table FOR XML PATH(''))

('123','321','456','321',...) -- < can be too long
```

but the Problem is, that @LIST gets too long, therefore I want to divide it based on the number of entries into multiple (sub)lists. For example a fixed size (e.g Maximum 3 Elements) would always look at three Elements until nothing is left.
I was thinking of using some kindof Loop

```
// some Kind of Loop
```

('123,321,456')

```
// end some Kind of loop
and in the next Loop
('321,982,66')

and finally (if less than 3 are remaining) only
```

('100')

how can i achieve this?

edit: the database is a MSSQL db.  if necessary I could sort the entries  but they also contain characters (not only numerical).  in fact the order doesnt matter.

Comment: Do you mean simply sorting the list by `length()`? `select * from tableX order by length(col1)` ?

Comment: Your question pre-supposes an ordering in the table.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, unless you have a column specifying the ordering, there is no way to answer this question.